# Como puedo validar un campo de tipo teléfono en un formulario con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Alguna solución para validar un campo de teléfono ya que lo tengo con una expresión básica pero al validar de forma correcta con números me muestra la validación como que sino estuviera ingresando números, lo tengo abierto con el navegador Firefox.

Etiqueta

```
<td>Teléfono:</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="teléfono" name="teléfono" maxlength="10" /></td>
```

Validación con JavaScript

```
function valtel(tel) {
var numbers = /^ [0 - 9] + $/;
if (tel.value.match(numbers)) {
  return true;
} else {
  alert("¡En el campo teléfono solo se aceptan números!");
  tel.focus();
  return false;
}
```

}

Captura de pantalla a un poniendo el número de 10 dígitos me bota la validación que le he asignado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con eliminar los espacios entre los números [0-9] debería validártelo bien:

```
^[0-9]+$
```

He comprobado que, cualquier número con 9 cifras o más, cumple ese patrón.

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que JavaScript es muy disciplinado en cuestión de espacios y cual símbolo que te falte.

Answer (score 0):

Cuidado con esos espacios, si lo que quieres es permitir espacios entre numeros pon:

```
^[0-9\s]+$
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.